# Five Slitherlinks

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, no-computers, grid-deduction, slitherlink

Solve five [Slitherlinks](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/slitherlink/), each with a unique solution.

[image: Four 4x4 Slitherlink puzzles]

Please say a word regarding (or show an image depicting) each solution method.

Comment: ... ***five***?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> [image]
>
>  The four slitherlinks give tetrominoes as answers. You can combine these to make a new grid (bottom left), which again has a unique solution (bottom right).

Comment: Ugh, you beat me by about 20 seconds. Do I have to post the answer unexplained first, and then edit in an explanation, like I do in PPCG?

Comment: @EricDuminil: You may be confusing what the first image represents. The four given grids have solutions that are tetrominoes. They can be put into a four by four grid in only one way which is what the first image shows. The second image then shows the solution to that puzzle.

Comment: @EricDuminil I've updated the answer a bit to make this clearer.

Answer (score 16):

I looked at other people's answers for the first four grids, and got the solutions from those. However, here's what I think the fifth grid is (minor spoilers for the other four grids):

> Place the four tetronimoes from the solutions to the first four grids together into a 2×2 square, without rotating them. There's only one way to do it:
>  `+-+-----+`
>  `|?|? 2 ?|`
>  `| +-+-+ |`
>  `|1 3|3|?|`
>  `| +-+ +-+`
>  `|?|?|2 ?|`
>  `+-+ +-+ |`
>  `|3 ? ?|?|`
>  `+-----+-+`

It has a unique solution:

> `..+-+-+-+`
>  `.?|?.2.?|`
>  `..+.+-+.+`
>  `.1|3|3|?|`
>  `..+-+.+.+`
>  `.?.?.2|?|`
>  `+-+-+-+.+`
>  `|3.?.?.?|`
>  `+-+-+-+-+`
>  This is copied directly from my notes; I was using `+` for an intersection the line definitely went through, and `.` for an intersection or edge it definitely didn't go through. The main observation is that the only way to get a line through a pair of 3s is to zigzag it past; if you zigzag it the other way, the 2 forces it to get stuck in the top-left corner, so the only possible path for the line goes round like this.

Answer (score 12):

I've found four slitherlink solutions, but I'm not certain how to construct the fifth...

> [image: blue is good, red is no good]
>  I initially thought the items in the tetrominoes were potential values for that square in a 2x2 Slitherlink, but there's no way to make that work without rearranging the squares. (ex. 3/3 on the right side is a contradiction, and 3/1 would force a 1 at the bottom left, which only has options for 3 or 2.)

Answer (score 11):

I think I have got the Answer to all 5:-

> [image]

Comment: ...well now I feel dumb :)

Comment: Nice try, but your fifth grid does not yield a *unique* solution and is thus not the intended Slitherlink puzzle. There are very many solutions to your fifth grid. The intended fifth grid has a unique solution.

Comment: I edited my question to make it clear that solutions should be unique.

Comment: Yeah, damn. How about now?

Comment: @KaranAtree This is unsolvable without tetrominoes. Your second 2 on the left of fifth has only one adjacent line.

Comment: @Silenus Congratulations, your comment has inspired [a new question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/50445/5373) :-)

Comment: So...has anyone come up with a puzzle where putting the grids together like this to make the fifth grid IS the solution?